# Inconsistent behavior of theme "Monochrome"

Tags: plotting, plot-themes, grid-lines

I am reporting inconsistent behavior of the "Monochrome" theme through this post when using a `GrayLevel[]` background. I am using version 12.2.0 Win7-x64.

Using a `GrayLevel[]` background for the `Plot`, the axes revert in color (turn lighter and remain visible) for other themes as the background gets darker but not for the "Monochrome". In other words it literally goes mono-chrome. The `GridLines` disappear as well and do not invert to a lighter color for all themes (not sure if there is an option to do so).

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Sin[2 x], Sin[x]}
  , {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
  
  , PlotTheme -> pt
  , Background -> GrayLevel[op1]
  
  (*,PlotStyle\[Rule]{{Dashed,Black},{Black}}
  ,Background->Directive[Red,Opacity[op1]]*)
  
  , GridLines -> Automatic
  , GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black, Dotted]
  , PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 2 \[Pi]}, {-1.1, 1.1}}
  , Axes -> False
  , Frame -> Automatic
  , FrameTicks -> Automatic
  ],
 {{op1, 1.0, "GrayLevel"
   , Appearance -> Labeled}, 0.0, 1.0}
 , {{pt, "Scientific", "Theme"
   , Appearance -> Labeled}
  , {"Default", "Scientific",
   "Detailed", "Web", "Monochrome"}}
 ]
```

[image]

**Question(s)**

1 - Is there a workaround for inverting plot colors but keeping the grid lines.

2 - Is this behavior version dependent?

3 - There used to be a `DefaultColor` directive that could invert the color for all items in the plot including the grid lines. It is obsolete now; I was wondering what its repalcement is?

---

For experiments without using `PlotTheme`, there is an alternate commented out section (two lines) that you can enable instead of the currently enabled statements.

---

**EDIT-1**

The reason I was  experimenting with themes was to create:

(1) Light and Dark themes for (print and web page outputs)

(2) I wanted to create an oscilloscope like display with grid lines and controlling the glow of the traces, but I am not there yet.

Comment: For non-monochrome themes the `FrameStyle` is gray instead of black.

Comment: A good observation ... By inconsistent, I mean not consistent with other themes being usable across the background gray level range. I should edit in the reason I was experimenting with it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I meant my comment as an explanation why this behaviour is consistent. I don't think that WRI's aim was to have themes that are all "usable across the background gray level range". After all, monochrome means a single color to style frames, axes, ticks, curves, labels, etc. Since it is by default black, you won't see them with a black background. You could use gray as your monochrome, but of course then you won't see anything on a gray background.